# Weird collision bug in Unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and something weird happens when I collide with a wall. It sorts of enter the wall and bounce off repeatedly. I putted physics materials and set the friction to 0 and it doesn't work either.

Comment: can you add screen shot of your scene and the objects/inspector view of attached components

Comment: I don't know how to upload my screenshots

Comment: you can paste pictures into your answer while editing it, you need to give more information

Comment: 截屏2020-05-05 下午10.15.57
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.16.01
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.16.03
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.16.06
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.15.20
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.15.33
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.15.30
截屏2020-05-05 下午10.15.40